# Using Jmeter, how to find how many simultaneous users  Web server will handle

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing

I have downloaded the JMeter and played around it. It is working fine. I have one quick question. I need help in this.

Using JMeter tool How can I say that given webserver handles efficiently n number of user at the given second or minute. 
. 
Please help me as soon as possible.

Thank You 
Regards 
Ganapathy

Answer (score 3):

Answer to that question is the very reason why we do performance testing.

We primarily want to find out how application response time grows as we increase the number of parallel users.

To find out you can start with [jMeter Plugins Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup) to gradually add users during a test. 
To visualize test results, use [Response Times vs Threads](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads) graph, which also comes with jMeter Plugins.

But that graph only shows average response time for specific number of users. To include time component use [Composite Graph](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/CompositeGraph) in which you'll include number of threads (users) and response time and you'll be able to see real time how response time changes with number of users.

That's where I'd start.

Comment: Links are broken: use http://testingfreak.com/jmeter/ultimate-thread-group/ and http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the number of requests (and threads that fire requests) and see how the answer time behaves. Part of the answer is the question which response time is acceptable for you. Also note that this will not be equal to real users as you are firing requests from a single machine and in a manner not comparable to real users requesting real pages.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am totally new to load testing. (I have 10 years of exp in development, this is the first time I am workingon laod testing). 1)I am not getting the following terminology which is used in your post "Part of the answer". Right now I am using Summary Report. 2) That mean to increase the number of request I can add many web site in the "Recording Controller" + increasing the thread and loop count in thread group. Whether I am right for the 2nd point.

Comment: @Gunny With "Part of the answer" i meant that there is no absolute answer to your question, because it might be acceptable to you if some users have to wait a second or two or even more for the web server's response.

Comment: Thankyou !  Whether following point is right 2) That mean to increase the number of request I can add many web site in the "Recording Controller" + increasing the thread and loop count in thread group. Whether I am right for the 2nd point.

Comment: @Gunny To increase the number of parallel requests you have to increase the number of threads. Increasing the loop count increases the number of sequential request.

Comment: JMeter offers an option for distributed request sending http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf . So sending requests from different machines can be simulated (still not as real as real users, but it is a step forward). Also I find it more efficient, because I have encountered situation where the requests from JMETER starting to get slow responses not because the application server is busy, but the testing machine could not handle the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [comparison](http://blog.olenepal.org/index.php/archives/300),  it may help you.